# Transforming event start and ends to state vectors in R

Tags: r, data.table, time-series, reduce

I am looking to transform a list of event start and end days to a vector of states, in which any day between the start and end is a 1, and outside is 0 (e.g. 2,4 -> c(0,1,1,1,0,0))

Each subject (keyed by id) can potentially have multiple start and end dates, in different rows, which need to be combined.

I have a solution that quite heavily leans on lapply (I have access to a supercomputer if need be, so could switch these to mclapply), but would prefer things got vectorised as far as possible, as the input data are potentially large (~250MB).

Can anyone see an avenue for reducing any steps in here?

```
require(data.table)

#The days that will be assessed for state
period = as.integer(1:8)
#Indices for days (they are not necessarily sequential)
dayInds = as.integer(1:length(period))

#Events for same ID will never overlap
dt = data.table(id = c("a","a","b","c","d","d","e"),
                start = c(1,6,3,3,3,5,5),
                end =   c(4,7,6,7,4,6,5))

# setkeyv(dt,colnames(dt))
setkeyv(dt,c("start","end"))

#Setup output table
stateData = data.table(id = dt$id)
#Remove "-" from days before index, they could get confusing, and initialise
#columns with zero
dayStrings = paste("d",gsub("-", "m", period),sep="")
stateData[,(dayStrings) := 0L]

#Find whether there is an overlap between a specified day in period and a
#subject's events
getStateOnDay = function(dayInd) {
  #Get day
  day = period[dayInd]
  #Create a table with the same number of rows as input dt, with a one day long
  #event on the input day
  overlapDays = unlist(foverlaps(data.table(start = day,end = day),
                                 dt,
                                 which=TRUE,
                                 nomatch = 0L)$yid)
  #Set those days to 1 in the state table
  set(stateData,overlapDays,dayInd+1L,1L)

}

#Get states for each row
lapply(dayInds,getStateOnDay)


#Create table for data with one row for each unique ID
reducedStateData = data.table(id = unique(stateData$id))
reducedStateData[,(dayStrings) := 0L]

#Sum a vector of logicals using OR
orSum = function(inputVec) {
  return(Reduce("|", c(inputVec)))
}

#Function for finding for each ID if they were in the state on a given day
reduceStatesByID = function(dayInd) {
  set(reducedStateData,
      NULL,
      dayInd+1L,
      stateData[,c(1,dayInd+1),with=FALSE][,as.integer(lapply(.SD, orSum)), by=id][,V1])
  return(NA)
}

#Apply reduction and sort
lapply(dayInds,reduceStatesByID)
setkey(reducedStateData,id)
```

Comment: So to cut to the chase here, you have `dt` and `reducedStateData` is your ultimate result you want?

Comment: @thelatemail yes, sorry should have made that clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an attempt using `Map` and a sequence, then `dcast`-ed to a wide format:

```
dcast(
  dt[, .(d=unlist(Map(seq, start, end)), val=1), by=id],
  id ~ d, value.var="val", fun.aggregate=sum, na.rm=TRUE
)

#   id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#1:  a 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
#2:  b 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
#3:  c 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
#4:  d 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
#5:  e 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

@Frank's suggestion in the comments seems quicker, probably mainly due to avoiding the `by=`:

```
dt[
    , .(t = unlist(L <- Map(seq, start, end)), id = rep(id, lengths(L)))
  ][, dcast(.SD, id ~ t, fun.agg = length)]
```

Comment: Or `dt[, .(t = unlist(L <- Map(seq, start, end)), id = rep(id, lengths(L)))][, dcast(.SD, id ~ t, fun.agg = length)]`, skipping the grouping. Then again, OP says `lapply` is slowing them down, so this might be a worse idea.

Comment: @Frank - it's certainly shorter code if nothing else! There is probably a more efficient variation though, no doubt.

Comment: @Frank Wow, that's ridiculous! Thank you both, looks like I've got a bit of work to do figuring out how it all works!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using data.table's extremely efficient `set` function after constructing an empty data.table with the correct dimensions (res) as well as a mapping from the rows of the the original matrix and the rows in the new matrix (resRows).

```
# construct empty data.table (ids and appropriate number of variables with 0s)
res <- data.table(id=unique(dt$id), matrix(0L, dt[, uniqueN(id)], max(dt$end)))

# get values for rows from id variable for placement into final data.table
resRows <- dt[, cumsum(rowid(id) == 1L)]

# fill in appropriate elements in data.table with 1s using set
for(i in seq_along(resRows)) set(res, resRows[i], dt[i, seq(start, end)] + 1L, 1L)
```

This returns

```
res
   id V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1:  a  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
2:  b  0  0  1  1  1  1  0
3:  c  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
4:  d  0  0  1  1  1  1  0
5:  e  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
```